# Is Texpad for Mac OS worth buying?

Tags: editors

I am currently using Texshop to write my thesis but I am not really satisfied with this editor. I stumbled upon Texpad but it has 30$ license. Does anyone have experience with this editor and if so, would you recommend buying it?

Comment: Did you try it or are you asking for user advice? In both cases unfortunately though this is not suitable on this site since the answers are only subjective yes and subjective no

Comment: As already noted, editor choice is very subject. The nearest we can do is to offer a comparison of features: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides.